# Automatically tweet on user upload (on my site)

Tags: php, twitter

I have a website where users can upload tracks.

When upload finished I would like to automatically tweet it using the Twitter account of the website.

And I would also like to enable the user (optionally) to tweet it using his/her account simultaneously.

Another thing I would like to do is tweet the track with the most votes every week.

On the Twitter page there are some API wrappers / libraries for PHP.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php

Any idea what library matches my requirements best?

Or if all match my requirements which one would be the easiest to implement?

Another question (the answer doesn't have to include this, but I'm just curious) why are there  5 different libraries?

EDIT

Or don't I have to use a library and just write the CURL calls myself?

Comment: Are you just asking for an example of how to post a status to Twitter using PHP?  Can you please clarify?

Comment: @AJ: I'm asking what library best suits my needs. Or perhaps I don't need to use a library at all.

Comment: There are different Twitter libraries for the same reason as there are different car companies.  Sure, they all do basically the same thing, but they are implemented differently, have differing levels of polish, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`Zend_Service_Twitter`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html) is a nice client, and there are [other opinions here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html).

To do what you want, you really only need to have a client that 1) supports authentication, and 2) can send a status update via the [`statuses/update`](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) API method.

One nice thing about status updates is that they are not rate limited, so you can have quite a high volume of outgoing tweets from your site.